# Is there a way to do recursive async calls on Rust without Box?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, future

Recursive calls with a retry count embedded into the argument is good for the mental model of the project because you don't have to keep thinking about the state of the object. The `retry_count` is passed in every call. Here's a simple implementation:

```
use std::future::Future;
use futures::future::{BoxFuture, FutureExt};

fn do_or_fail() -> std::result::Result<(),()> {
    Ok(())
}

fn do_something<'a>(
        retry_count: u32
) -> BoxFuture<'a, std::result::Result<(), ()>> {
    async move {
        match do_or_fail() {
            Ok(_) => Ok(()),
            Err(_) => do_something(retry_count -1).await
        }
    }.boxed()
}

fn main() {
    do_something(3);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9a14821d75640c77cb012362f32f18c)

The problem is that this requires a dynamic allocation at every call so it can return the `BoxFuture`. This is because of how async is implemented in Rust. It generates a state machine for every await call so the return type is not Sized.

What would be good ways to overcome dynamic allocation in recursive async calls?

Comment: "Is there a way to do recursive async calls on Rust without Box?" no. "What would be good ways to overcome dynamic allocation in recursive async calls?" don't

Answer (score 1):

While it technically doesn't *overcome* the problem (it just hides it), I can recommend the crate `async_recursion`.

https://crates.io/crates/async-recursion

```rust
use async_recursion::async_recursion;
use tokio;

fn do_or_fail() -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
    Ok(())
}

#[async_recursion]
async fn do_something(retry_count: u32) -> std::result::Result<(), ()> {
    match do_or_fail() {
        Ok(_) => Ok(()),
        Err(_) => do_something(retry_count - 1).await,
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    do_something(3).await.unwrap()
}
```

I don't think you actually *can* overcome dynamic allocation in async calls, that's just how async works in general.